# Подключение checkBox к адаптеру

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте.
Попробовал добавить checkBox к адаптеру, но он работает не корректно. Я отмечаю один элемент, но отмеченные кнопки появляются в других группах.
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, так ли я его подключил в адаптер?

//разметка

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="40dp"
android:background="#99D6D6"
android:clickable="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="40dp"
tools:context=".ExpandableListMainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="39dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/childImage"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textViewChild"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="#1919A3"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        />

   <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkBoxColor" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </CheckBox>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

//адаптер, добавил check в getChildView:

```
package com.example.expandablelistview1;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.CheckedTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childtems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;
    CheckBox checkboxColor;

    // constructor
    public MyExpandableAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern)
    {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childtems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) 
    {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // method getChildView is called automatically for each child view.
    //  Implement this method as per your requirement
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

         // get the textView reference and set the value
        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewChild);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        checkboxColor = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBoxColor);

        // set the ClickListener to handle the click event on child item
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(checkboxColor.isChecked()){
                Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        return convertView;
    }

    private CheckBox findViewById(int checkboxcolor) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    // method getGroupView is called automatically for each parent item
    // Implement this method as per your requirement
    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_view, null);
        }

        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));
        ((CheckedTextView) convertView).setChecked(isExpanded);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childtems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() 
    {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) 
    {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition)
    {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) 
    {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() 
    {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вспомним, как работает **ListView**  
В нем существуют одновременно количество **View** видимых элементов списка +2 (верхний и нижний). При прокручивании списка **View** используются повторно.   
То есть, когда вы делаете **CheckBox** чекнутым, при его "реюзинге" он остается "чекед". То есть, надо где-то запоминать его состояние. На пример, в модели элемента списка (У вас это вроде переменная **child**), и в инициализации очередного элемента списка выставлять ему "чекед" каждый раз. (В вашем методе **getChildView**)

Comment: То есть каждый раз при открытии списка нужно запоминать отмеченные элементы, потом при закрытии отчищать "чекед". Тогда при повторном открытии списка "чекед" появится на сохраненных элементах?

Comment: @ed8009 я писал совершенно о другом, но да